# Laravel - assert not soft deleted? Inverse? - Laravel Tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, automated-tests

Laravels test suite has an assertion called

```
$this->assertSoftDeleted()
```

But is there the inverse? To assert that something is not soft deleted?

I've tried `assertDatabaseHas` but doesn't work.

I have done it this way `$this->assertTrue(! $goal->fresh()->trashed());`

Works perfect.

But is there another, better, more ---elegant--- and laravel's way?

Comment: If you have a look in SoftDeletes.php (The PHP trait which handles all softdelete related functionality) you can see that there is no inverse of trashed(). You could make your own method on the model which uses the SoftDeletes trait.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something not being soft deleted just means that the `deleted_at` column is null. You could use the `assertDatabaseHas` method where that column is empty:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('goals', [
    'id' => $goal->id,
    'deleted_at' => null
]);
```

If you wanted to make this a bit more dynamic, you could extend your base `TestCase` class with a custom method that will do this for you and allow you to keep your tests with a readable assertion name, and additionally do things for you like find the appropriate table/column names automatically:

```
public function assertModelNotSoftDeleted(Model $model)
{
    return $this->assertDatabaseHas($model->getTable(), [
        $model->getKeyName() => $model->getKey(),
        $model::DELETED_AT => null,
    ]);
}
```